# AWS Elastic Beanstalk : 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.1 Spring boot application - tried port 5000

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed a simple Spring boot application to Elastic Beanstalk but when I try to access /serviceinfo , or any path for this purpose, it's always showing `Health
Degraded` in the dash board I get this error 
502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.1

The app works locally

but on EBS logs I read :
`2019/03/02 06:55:49 [error] 3298#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 111.215.59.25, server: , request: "GET /serviceinfo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/serviceinfo", host: "myservice.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"`
Because I've deployed other Spring boot applications in the past, I know about `server.port=5000`, I've set it in my Spring Application properties, and when it didn't work I've set it again in EBS as an environment variable.
but I still get the same error.
Also used `SpringBootServletInitializer` in the main class, but that didn't help either.

What else can I try to make it run